# ls, Find commands hang out to specific directory

Tags: unix

I am trying to run ls, Find commands on a specific directory in unix and it is getting hanged. I searched online and tried some of the solutions but none is working. It is a very huge directory and even df -k * is not working. I tried strace too but same issue and even I tried copying the stuff to another directory by using cp *  but again same issue. So please help me out here.

P.S:This is not any NFS mount issue as well. Treid mount |grep  and I am not having super user permissions

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does bare `ls` "hang" as well? What does `ls|wc` say?

Comment: yes both hang as well

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue on AWS EC2 instance the directory was on EBS volume we attached separately.

Issue was because of the D state processes.

how to check D state process?
command: `ps aux | awk '{print $8}'|grep D`

Process goes into the "**D**" state when they are doing IO operation. Once IO operation completes processes generally comes out of "**D**" state, but sometimes processes gets stuck into "**D**" state. "**D**" state means uninterruptible sleep(process doing IO operation).

In this case we need to **reboot** the server to remove D state process.

**My problem solved after server restart**